# Implement containsKey when key is an object

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, overriding, equals

I have this class:

```
Public Class AdDimensionsToAdDetails
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function equals(adDimensions As AdDimensions) As Boolean
        If adDimensions Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If

        Return Me.adDimensionsToAdDetails.Keys.First().width = adDimensions.width AndAlso
            Me.adDimensionsToAdDetails.Keys.First().height = adDimensions.height

    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property adDimensionsToAdDetails As Dictionary(Of AdDimensions, AdDetails)
        Get
            Return New Dictionary(Of AdDimensions, AdDetails) From {
                {New AdDimensions(300, 250), New AdDetails(New MinMaxJobsCount(3, 3), True)},
                {New AdDimensions(300, 50), New AdDetails(New MinMaxJobsCount(1, 1), False)},
                {New AdDimensions(728, 90), New AdDetails(New MinMaxJobsCount(3, 3), True)},
                {New AdDimensions(160, 600), New AdDetails(New MinMaxJobsCount(3, 7), True)}
            }

        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

I want to check if `adDimensionsToAdDetails` contains a key of 300,250.

So I have tried:

```
dim adDimensions as new AdDimensions(300,250)

' it contains the key
if (AdDimensionsToAdDetails.adDimensionsToAdDetails.ContainsKey(adDimensions)) then

End If
```

I read that I need to override `equals`.

So I tried it, but I get: 
`function 'equals' cannot be declared 'overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dictionary` class is implemented as a hashtable.  When comparing a key value, the `Dictionary` will call the `GetHashCode` method on the key item in  question and only if it has an entry for that particular hashcode will it then call the item's `Equals` method to verify equality.

Therefore, to use the `Dictionary(Of AdDimensions, AdDetails).ContainsKey` method, you will need to override both the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods the class AdDimensions inherits from `System.Object`.

The following is one possible implementation, based on your code.

```
Class AdDimensions
    Public Sub New(height As Int32, width As Int32)
        Me.height = height
        Me.width = width
    End Sub
    Public height As Int32
    Public width As Int32

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Dim other As AdDimensions = TryCast(obj, AdDimensions)
        Dim ret As Boolean
        If other IsNot Nothing Then
            ret = (Me.width = other.width) AndAlso (Me.height = other.height)
        End If
        Return ret
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return Me.width Xor Me.height
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: It works but I have a question..
As I read, two equal objects are guaranteed to have equal hashcodes.. but, because there are different versions of the .NET Framework, it can return the same value for different objects. Then we need the equal? for verifying it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the framework version.  Two different objects of the same type may yield the same hash code.  If you are not familiar with what hash tables are and how they work, them research them.  The Equals method evaluates those parameters that you decide that should allow the objects to be treated as equal.  Equality does not imply same object; just that they have equal defining characteristics.

Comment: Thanks a lot TnTinMn

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the signature of a method you want to override.  The `Object.Equals` method has one parameter of type `Object`.  Your override must have the same.

That said, I just realised that you have that method in the wrong class.  It would need to be in the `AdDimensions` class if the intent is to compare two instances of that type.